# Scanner Happy Numbers Java

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

Can't understand one thing in below code, hope someone might help:

```
public class Solution {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = in.nextInt();
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      if (in.nextInt() % 7 == 0){
        count++;
      }
    }
    System.out.printf("%d", count);
  }

}
```

How does the `Scanner` exactly works? I thought this code will only expect 1 input from the keyboard, but what it does is taking 1st number as a length of the array and afterwards gives me a chance to enter those values.

For instance, if I enter 3, then I'll be able to add 3 elements, if 6 then 6 and so on. But I can't see no array in this code.
Maybe I'm missing something with the for loop?

Comment: there is a `for` loop, arrays do not matter.

Comment: What is a happy number?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder in this case the one that is divided into 7 without remainder

Comment: If you didn't want to be asked multiple inputs, why is there a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `in.nextInt()` in the loop so every time you get new value to enter, maybe you want to put N%7 instead ?

Answer (score 0):

The `nextInt()` method accepts the very next `int` value **from the Scanner object**. Since you passed an `InputStream` (`System.in`) to the constructor of the Scanner object, if the object is 'empty' - devoid of any `int` value in this case - it asks the user to input a number again.

When you first accepted the number from the user, it got stored in N, but then the Scanner object became empty.

So every time you call `nextInt()` in the loop, you're accepting a value from the keyboard (the user). That is equivalent to storing all inputs from the user in an array and then doing the calculations, except the operation here is being done immediately on the input

Comment: The use of nextInt is fine... You type N, it's how many numbers to check, then you type each number

Comment: @cricket_007 I've updated my code now. It's just that I misunderstood the problem earlier.

Comment: @Andrew If you feel that your question has been answered, please consider marking an answer as 'helpful', for further references.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder do you mean pushing an arrow "This answer is useful" or clicking a check mark to accept an answer? Because I did both, answers were helpful

Comment: @Andrew Marking an answer as helpful means the check mark.

Comment: @Andrew The arrow stands for a vote i.e. an upvote or downvote.

Comment: @Andrew Although upvoting tells future viewers that the answer was good, marking it as helpful tells them that that answer was the most useful and explanatory.

Comment: Remember, you can only mark one answer as helpful, so use it wisely!

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder thank you for the detailed explanation. I'll take it into account!